How to add values labels to the fib levels in the graphic?
l was wondering how do l add these value labels (0,0.11,0.25,0.3,0.38) to the right side of the fib lines FStyles:
f1Lvl = f1Tog?input.float(0, title = "", group = fib_group, inline = "1"):na
f2Lvl = f2Tog?input.float(0.11, title = "", group = fib_group, inline = "2"):na
f3Lvl = f3Tog?input.float(0.25, title = "", group = fib_group, inline = "3"):na
f4Lvl = f4Tog?input.float(0.30, title = "", group = fib_group, inline = "4"):na
f5Lvl = f5Tog?input.float(0.38, title = "", group = fib_group, inline = "5"):na

f1Style = input.string("___", title = "", options = ["___","- - -",". . ."], group = fib_group, inline = "1")
f2Style = input.string("___", title = "", options = ["___","- - -",". . ."], group = fib_group, inline = "2")
f3Style = input.string("___", title = "", options = ["___","- - -",". . ."], group = fib_group, inline = "3")
f4Style = input.string("___", title = "", options = ["___","- - -",". . ."], group = fib_group, inline = "4")
f5Style = input.string("___", title = "", options = ["___","- - -",". . ."], group = fib_group, inline = "5")

l would like the values to appear next to the input string lines on the right side (end) of the lines.
thank you,
l tried adding label.new on it but it says the script can't be compiled.

There is no text parameter on the line; instead, you can use a label that has the same coordinate as the line's start or end, for example:
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

type myDrawing
    line ln
    label lb 

signal = ta.crossover(close,ta.ema(open,10))

if signal 
    myDrawing.new(line.new(bar_index, high, bar_index+5, high), label.new(bar_index+5, high, "sometext", style = label.style_none))


